# React app didn't install on my local computer

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, npm

`npm install -g create-react-app` - when I run this command it failed and shows some error like this:

> ```
> npm ERR! code EACCES
> npm ERR! syscall mkdir
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
> npm ERR! errno -13
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'] {
> npm ERR!   errno: -13,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
> npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
> npm ERR! }
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/leon/.npm/_logs/2021-08-25T16_02_40_435Z-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `sudo` before the npm command

`sudo npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: @leon-islam, if you find this question useful and solved your problem then mark the question as answered, please.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking if permissions are setup correctly too: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try to install npm / yarn with admin permissions sudo XXXXX